# A⋃(B⋂C)=(A⋃B)⋂(AUC) prove it?

Tags: proof-writing, set-partition

We can see more easily with Venn diagram.  I want to prove it without Venn diagram . I tried like this.                   A⋃(B⋂C)=(A⋃B)⋂(AUC) . Let x∊A⋃(B⋂C) Then x∊A or x∊B⋂C . First assume that x∊A Then x∊A⋃B and x∊A⋃C ....
A few step later. Let x∊(A⋃B)⋂(AUC) so x∊A⋃B and x∊A⋃C.But I cant continue . How can I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may continue your proof as follows.

If $$x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$ Then we consider two cases.

Case 1)  $x\in A$ which implies $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$

Case 2) $x\notin A$  then $x$ must be in both $B$ and $C$ therefore it is in  $B\cap C$ which makes it $x\in A\cup (B\cap C)$